# H2 cluster weird behavior : fake referential Integrity violation on foreign key

Tags: sql, database, cluster-computing, h2

I run H2 in cluster mode with 2 nodes.

I have two tables. A parent, and a child. The child contains a foreign key to the ID of a row of the parent table.
I'm experiencing a weird issue that I can not understand : everything is working OK until I violate a unique constraint.

Steps:
- Everything is working normally
- I violate (by purpose here) a Unique constraint
- Now when adding child rows, I get a referential integrity violation on the foreign key (parent.id), but the child row is properly added.

Script:

```
create table CHILD(id int auto_increment, name varchar(255), fkey int);
create table PARENT(id int auto_increment, name varchar(255) UNIQUE);

ALTER TABLE `CHILD` ADD FOREIGN KEY (fkey) REFERENCES `PARENT` (`id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE;

-- Insert the first parent, id will be '1'. Then insert the child, this works.
insert into PARENT(name) values('parent1');
insert into CHILD(name, fkey) values('child1', 1); 

-- By purpose, we violate the Unique constraint violation on PARENT.name : Unique index or primary key violation: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_8 ON PUBLIC.PARENT(NAME) VALUES ( /* 2 */ 'parent1' )"
insert into PARENT(name) values('parent1');

-- Then I delete this parent (by cascade, all childs are deleted)
delete from PARENT where name='parent1';

-- Then I re-insert this parent, this create the row (3, "parent3")
insert into PARENT(name) values('parent3');

-- I try to insert a child with the parent '3', 
-- I get a Referential integrity constraint violation: "CONSTRAINT_3: PUBLIC.CHILD FOREIGN KEY(FKEY) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PARENT(ID) (3)"
insert into CHILD(name, fkey) values('child3', 3); 
-- But the child was propertly added !
```

The workaround I found is to replace the last `insert into` with :

```
insert into CHILD(name, fkey) values('child3', SELECT ID from parent where name='parent3');
```

But this is so weird, because `SELECT ID from parent where name='parent3'` returns `3`.

It also happens when using sequences instead of auto_increment.
It *does not* happens when I don't use auto_increment or sequences and so when I manage the id myself (but I don't want to).
**It does not happens when I run H2 without cluster.**
Tested with H2 v1.3.176 and H2 v1.4.189.

Can somebody explain this ? Did I make a mistake here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H2 main developper thomas mueller answered this question on github:

> This is one of the documented limitations of the cluster feature, see
>   also "Clustering Algorithm and Limitations": "Using auto-increment and
>   identity columns is currently not supported."
>
> I'm afraid it's hard to fix it. I suggest to not use the cluster
>   feature for this reason. Support for it will probably be removed in
>   the future. I hope a new cluster / automatic failover feature can be
>   added, but this will take some time.
>
> But this might be interesting for you: https://github.com/shesse/h2ha

See [issue on github](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/274)

I managed to get it working: using sequences and inserting in two times:
- Get the nextval for this table sequence, eg: **nextid** =`select childsequence.nextval from dual`
- Then do your `INSERT INTO child` and specify the id `nextid`